# Конвертация Date в LocalDateTime через Stream API

Tags: java, datetime, java-stream, localdate

У меня есть внешняя библиотека, содержащая три класса Airport, Aircraft, Flight.
По заданию надо вернуть список рейсов, вылетающих в ближайшие 2 часа.
Написал код, он точно работает:

```
 public static List<Flight> findPlanesLeavingInTheNextTwoHours(Airport airport) {
    LocalDateTime dateNow = LocalDateTime.now();

    return airport.getTerminals().stream() //получаем терминал
            .flatMap(terminal -> terminal.getFlights().stream()) //только так можно получить Date
            .filter(flight -> flight.getType().equals(Flight.Type.DEPARTURE)) //выбираем рейсы на вылет
            .filter(flight -> flight.getDate()          /*
                    .toInstant()                              вынести преобразование в отдельный метод
                    .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())     */
                    .toLocalDateTime().isAfter(dateNow) && flight.getDate()
                    .toInstant()
                    .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                    .toLocalDateTime().isBefore(dateNow.plusHours(2)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Получать методы Flight можно только через stream. Мне надо преобразование Date(тип изменять нельзя) в LocalDateTime вынести в отдельный метод, а затем передавать значение в метод findPlanesLeavingInTheNextTwoHours(Airport airport), то есть:

```
public static ? convertToLD(?) {
    // Date -> LocalDateTime 
}
```

Не понимаю, как написать метод, а потом сравнить.
Надеюсь, что я понятно описал вопрос, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение, вдруг кому-то поможет в будущем:

```
 public static List<Flight> findPlanesLeavingInTheNextTwoHours(Airport airport) {
    LocalDateTime dateNow = LocalDateTime.now();

    return airport.getTerminals().stream()
            .flatMap(terminal -> terminal.getFlights().stream())
            .filter(flight -> flight.getType().equals(Flight.Type.DEPARTURE))
            .filter(flight -> modifiedDate(flight)
                    .isAfter(dateNow) && modifiedDate(flight)
                    .isBefore(dateNow.plusHours(2)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public static LocalDateTime modifiedDate(Flight date) {
    return LocalDateTime
            .ofInstant(date.getDate().toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
public LocalDateTime convertToLocalDateTimeViaInstant(Date dateToConvert) {
    return dateToConvert.toInstant()
      .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
      .toLocalDateTime();
}
```

Comment: Это немного не то, я описал, каким способом надо получить дату, но спасибо!